# How can I specify a path to my manifest file for artifact manually in xml?

Tags: intellij-idea

Due to bug in Ubuntu or Intellij idea I can't choose a manifest using Artifacts window, it's too small and can't be scrolled or resized.
Have I any variant to do it in artifact xml manually?
My artifact configuration:

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="javafx" name="fss">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/out/artifacts/fss</output-path>
    <properties id="javafx-properties">
      <options>
        <option name="appClass" value="com.contedevel.fss.Main" />
        <option name="description" value="" />
        <option name="htmlPlaceholderId" value="" />
        <option name="title" value="Fish School Search" />
        <option name="vendor" value="ConteDevel" />
        <option name="version" value="1.0.1" />
      </options>
    </properties>
    <root id="root">
      <element id="archive" name="fss.jar">
        <element id="module-output" name="fss" />
      </element>
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000605730-Native-bundle-is-missing-in-Intellij-Idea-2018-1-Ultimate

Comment: @CrazyCoder, thank you! Although a logic of Idea developers is weird for me... Why can they not add a scrolling or an ability to resize?..